# server error sent to client in express

Tags: node.js, express

In the following node.js server code, since "ABCDE" is not a defined a variable, error is thrown when '/upload' is requested. What confused me is that, the error stack trace printed on the console at server side is sent back to the client, which is unsafe.

How can I prevent that, other than catch that error?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(ABCDE);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have the answer in your question.  You need error-handling middleware (`app.use` a function with an arity of 4) to handle the error.

You just need to add the error-handling middleware **after** the router.  Your example puts the the error handler above the the router.

Either move the `app.use(function (err, req, res, next))` to the bottom of your code or insert

```
app.use(app.router);
```

above the error handler.

[Refer to the documentation for more information about error handlers.](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: This link is now broken.

Comment: ... and now there is a redirect. So the link is again working.